# Inner fragments communication implementation;

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I was working on an app that needs some data transfer between fragments and stumbled upon two version of doing it.
Here are very similar versions of implementing a listener. Which one do you think is better for communication between fragments? Or maybe some other implementation? Another question is: Is another interface is needed to send data from the second  fragment through MainAvtivity back to the first one or is there a simpler way of doing that?

Thank You

First:

```
class FragOne extends ListFragment
             {     
              ListenerInterface listener;

      public void onAttach(Content content)
            {
              try{
                  listener = (ListenerInterface).content;
                  }catch ClassCastException..
               super.onAttach(content);
            }
                 ...
       public void OnListItemClick(ListView, View,position,id)
            {
             listener.doSmth(someData);
            }

       public interface ListenerInterface
            {
              public void doSmth(someData);
            }

      }
class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragOne.ListInterface
{
    ....

 public void doSmth(someData)
    {
       //sending data to second fragment
    }
}
```

Or the second one:

```
class FragOne extends ListFragment
      {     
      ListenerInterface listener;

            ...
       public void OnListItemClick(ListView, View,position,id)
            {
             listener.doSmth(someData);
            }

       public void assignListener(Activity activity)
              {
                this.listener=(ListenerInterface)activity;

              }
       public interface ListenerInterface
            {
               public void doSmth(someData);
            }

      }
class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragOne.ListInterface
{
    ....
    public void onCreate(Bundle s)
          }
            FragOne fragOne = new FragOne();
            FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentmentManager...       
             ...
             ...commit();
            fragOne.assignListener(this);
          }

   public void doSmth(someData)
    {
       //sending data to second fragment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would recommend first one just because of the code in the onAttach. Creating a function just to call that part seems ridiculous and it's easy to forget that you would have to call that function before you can use your interface (especially for a newbie). You will get NullPointerException.

The first method is good, only if FragOne is the only one using the interface. Otherwise create a separate interface in a java class that other fragments can also use in a similar way.

You can have multiple methods defined inside one interface and multiple fragments may use some or all the methods in the interface. But remember, one interface is accessed by only one fragment at a time. One fragment may access multiple interfaces.

Comment: Thank you @suku for answering the question.

Comment: You are welcome Roman. Can you please mark the answer as correct?